# Get name resolution in a C++ project

Tags: java, c++, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

**Problem**

I am developing a Java ***stand-alone*** static testing tool for C++ projects. In this tool, I need to get name resolution inside a project. 
For example, given two statements in a function:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x + 1;
```

By using name resolution on the variable x of the second statement, I detect that it is declared at the first one.

**Current solution**

Firstly, I used Eclipse CDT plugin (only a part of CDT) to create abstract syntax trees (AST). More clearly, each of source code files in the testing project is analyzed to construct a corresponding AST. However, these ASTs do not contain name resolution. Therefore, I have to analyze AST to detect name resolution. My current solution seems to be good, but for large-scale projects and complex structures, it definitely fails.

Later, I have known that information about name resolution could be obtained automatically by using Eclipse CDT. But I need to create a *stand-alone* tool (outside Eclipse), it means that I could not integrate my tool into CDT.

I have known that C++ uses static name resolution rather than dynamic approach. So, this information about name resolution could be collected. Can you suggest me any further ideas to overcome my issue?

**Updated (based on recommendations below)**

Some suggest me as follows, and my response.

**+ Use Clang**

It is true that Clang supports to analyse C++ files (and C files also), and there is no denying that Clang is a good choice. However, my language I want to use is **Java**. Currently, I only find one (i.g., Eclipse CDT plugin). As I said, CDT plugin does not support name resolution when I try to use it outside Eclipse CDT IDE.

My current Java stand-alone tool, namely [CFT4Cpp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3ugnLKmC6g), uses CDT plugin to parse C/C++ program. Due to the limit of CDT plugin, I have analyzed name resolution by using some simple algorithms. However, these algorithms fail when analyzing complex projects in terms of syntaxes.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: Both clang and gcc have libraries which can help you parse C and C++ code. Check them out.

Comment: @Yunnosch This question is not about interchangeability between C and C++, all other case is generally too broad. You can't ask a question for two language. This question do not differ, it's too broad. (and no you can't use the same parser for a c and for c++), it's just they are generally in the same package.

Comment: @Stargateur I think your comment is correct to some extent. I modified my question as specific as possible.

Comment: @Stargateur You cannot use one parser for C and C++, true. You can however still make one tool for both languages using two parsers. But now that OP has restricted to C++, luckily the whole discussion is unneeded.

Comment: If you are an academic, send me some email mentioning the URL of your question. I might be interested by some academic collaboration...

Comment: You say you're writing a standalone tool outside of Eclipse, but it uses CDT. How do you use CDT outside of Eclipse? CDT has dependencies on the Eclipse Platform.

Comment: Anyways, if you are somehow able to get a CDT AST in your code, why can't you use CDT's existing facilities for name resolution, like `IASTName.resolveBinding()`?

Comment: @HighCommander4 I downloaded CDT, then selected necessary libraries from this plug-in in such a way that my tool could run outside Eclipse. You could see these libraries here (https://github.com/ducanhnguyen/CDT/tree/master/cdt).

Comment: @HighCommander4 Yeah. That great! Now I could perform name resolution in a file. However, I have a problem as follows: How can I perform name resolution in a project? For example, assume we have "int x = a;" (where a is defined in a header file). I want to know the definition of a. Suggest me if you have any idea. Thank you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have just sent further information about the tool to your email. Please check it.

Comment: To use information from header files, the project needs to have an index, and the AST needs to be created with the index as a parameter (e.g. `ITranslationUnit.getAST(IIndex)`). The index can be created and obtained using `IIndexManager`.

Answer (score 4):

C++ is a *very complex* programming language (and different of C). Parsing it is a very difficult task (*many* years of work - perhaps a lifetime if working alone - if you do that from scratch).

So **build your tool above some *existing* C++ parsing technology**. You could use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), perhaps thru GCC [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (see [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html)), or [Edison C++](https://www.edg.com/c) frontend etc. Free software C++ compilers are huge beasts (several millions of lines) continuously evolving and growing, and mastering them requires a lot of work. BTW, you could use common [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (e.g. [JSONRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsonrpc) or other approaches) or [foreign function interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) techniques (e.g. [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)) to use C++ compiler frameworks from Java.

> However, my language I want to use is Java.

**Be pragmatic.** So code a small part in C++ (above existing parsers, e.g. from C++ compilers), and the rest in Java.

<sup>(for an academic prototype, using some inter-process communication between an adapted compiler in C++ and some tool in Java is probably the less difficult; however, you will have to code several thousands lines on the compiler side in C++, since C++ is complex; and you'll need more on your Java side; BTW, you probably need a bit of practice in C++ to be able to design useful things for it...)</sup>

<sup>(since you probably won't find complete C++ compilers or front-ends in Java)</sup>

Even if building your thing above an existing C++ parser, the task is not easy and could consume several months of your time. And existing C++ parsers are evolving (e.g. the internal representations of GCC is slightly changing from one version to the next one). So you need to budget the evolution of these parsers.

And parsing C++ is itself an ill defined task (think of preprocessing, template expansions, etc....). You need to define on what form of C++-related code representation you want to work on. Of course the C++ standard have several releases, etc.

Perhaps you should consider asking your manager (or get some research grant, if you are academic) to work full time on that for several years. But ask yourself if it is worthwhile....

Alternatively, if you restrict yourself to one C++ project, consider instead defining some project-specific conventions, generating some C++ code and some tests in it. YMMV.

Another approach (which works on Linux, but probably not everywhere else) is to ask your user to compile with debug information enabled (e.g. with `g++ -g` if he uses [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and to parse [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information.

<sup>BTW, I did work on similar goals: a few years ago in [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/), and now in my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) github project (temporary name, will change). Be sure to get funded for several years of work full time, since your goal is very ambitious.</sup>

Comment: You make me a great day. Many thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

There is more to using a an existing and wide-spread compiler over your own solution then the complexity involved in the implementation.

C++ is now an ever-changing language. Since `C++11` the road map is a new version of the standard every 3 years. And they sicked with it: we have C++11, C++14, C++17 and C++20 is on track.

You will have a very very difficult and time consuming challenge ahead just for staying up with the changes in standard.

For example I show you just 1 change per version that you would need to add support for. Can you / are you willing to support each new standard version in its entirely? Or are you going to end up with an application/tool that by the time it gets out of development is already obsolete?

C++98:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x + 1;
```

C++11:

```
auto x = 0;
auto y = x + 1;
```

C++14

```
[](auto x) { auto y = x; }
```

C++17

```
if (const auto [iter, inserted] = mySet.insert(value); inserted)
```

C++20 hopefully this:

```
template <class T, class F, class P>
   requires requires(T x, F f, P p) {
       f(x);
       {p(f(x))} -> bool;
   }
auto bar(T x, F f, P p)
{
   //
}
```

With a solution based on an compiler like gcc or clang you have all these taken care of by the compiler itself. All you need to do is use it for your own purpose.

Comment: The best answer I have ever seen about the feasibility of my approach. Vote for you definitely.